# Counting Repeated Objects In NSArray Only Working Some of Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nscountedset

My `NSArray` inside of a `PFObject` needs to be sorted.  The `PFObject` contains multiple items, including an array, which contains days of the week, and I need to know which date is repeated most often for each item inside the PFObject.  Inside my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (since I need to know it for each item in the TableView, I have this:

```
NSArray *yourArrayhere = object[@"DatesSuggested"];

    if (yourArrayhere == NULL) {
        //cell.text = @"No votes have been cast for this activity yet.";


    }
    else {
        NSCountedSet *setOfObjects = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:yourArrayhere];

        //Declaration of objects
        NSString *mostOccurringObject = @"";
        NSUInteger highestCount = 0;

        //Iterate in set to find highest count for a object
        for (NSString *strObject in setOfObjects)
        {
            NSUInteger tempCount = [setOfObjects countForObject:strObject];

                highestCount = tempCount;
                mostOccurringObject = strObject;
                NSLog(@"MOSTO%@", mostOccurringObject);
            NSLog(@"MOSTC%lu", (unsigned long)highestCount);

        }
        NSString *allcombined = [[[[[[[@"Currently there are " stringByAppendingString:votesFor] stringByAppendingString:@" votes for and "] stringByAppendingString:votesAgainst] stringByAppendingString:@" votes against "] stringByAppendingString:object[@"Title"]] stringByAppendingString:@", with the most suggested date being "] stringByAppendingString:mostOccurringObject];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = allcombined;
        NSString *toSave = [mostOccurringObject stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %lu", (unsigned long)highestCount]];
        NSLog(@"Highest %@", toSave);
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:toSave forKey:cell.textLabel.text];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
```

This works some of the time.  One of the arrays has `(Monday, Monday, Monday, Thursday)` in it, and it shows Monday being most popular, with 3 votes for it.  Another array is identical, but shows Thursday being most popular.  I'm stumped on why it is behaving this way.

Comment: You have to check if `tempCount` is actually higher than `highestCount` in your loop.  Right now it just returns whichever one it checks last.

Comment: Wrap the last 4 lines in the loop in a `if (tempCount > highestCount) { ... }`

Comment: Yea, I'm a block head.  First for missing it and then asking that question.  Aargh, long Monday.  Thanks!

Comment: Dan, you should post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: In Swift would that be a "Closure head?"

Comment: Might I also recommend taking a look at `[NSString stringWithFormat...]`. You'll love it, I promise.